# Is there a way to generate a signal on QSlider value increased

Tags: qt, slider, signals-slots

I'm trying to trigger a distinct signal from a QSlider for when it increases or decreases. Unfortunately due to restrictions in the program i'm creating outside of my control I cannot track the value of the slider and just do a comparison.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can't use `valueChanged(int)` to decide if the value increased or decreased, since you can't track the value. However, you need to do this, since QSlider doesn't have distinct signals for an increased / decreased value.

Use this helper class to keep track of the current value. It remaps the signal `valueChanged(int)` of the provided target object to the new signals `valueIncreased(int)` and `valueDecreased(int)` telling the (absolute) difference.

```
class ValueChangeTracker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int v;
public:
    ValueChangeTracker(QObject *target) :
        QObject(target)
    {
        connect(target, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(changed(int)));
        v = target->property("value"); // or ->value() if you specifically use QSlider* instead of QObject* as the target type
    }
signals:
    void valueIncreased(int);
    void valueDecreased(int);
private slots:
    void changed(int newValue) {
        int diff = newValue - v;
        v = newValue;
        if(diff > 0) emit valueIncreased(diff);
        if(diff < 0) emit valueDecreased(-diff);
    }
};
```

To use it, simply create a new instance of this class and connect to its signals. In the QObject tree, it becomes a child of the target object, so you don't have to keep the pointer to an instance.

```
QSlider *mySlider = ...
ValueChangeTracker *tracker = new ValueChangeTracker(mySlider);
connect(tracker, SIGNAL(valueIncreased(int)), ...);
connect(tracker, SIGNAL(valueDecreased(int)), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

`QSlider` emits the signal `valueChanged`, just connect it to a slot:

```
mySlider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_mySlider_valueChanged)
```

and to your tests there and emit a custom signal if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, maybe an example would help. But if you look at the documentation for [QSlider](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qslider.html#details), it emits signal `valueChanged(int)` when the value of the slider changes.